# Start APP after Installation via android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
             android:name="com.android.test.receiver"
             android:exported="true"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
                 <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />                              
                 </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**receiver.java**

```
package com.android.test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)     {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Step by step:

1. i start my Virtual Device in Eclipse
2. after booting i install the test APP
3. i open terminal, run command `telnet localhost 5554` `sms send 01 test`
4. my Virtual Device receives and displays test SMS, but don't fire my APP

My Question: why? When i create MainActivity and open the APP Window, my APP receives callbacks on "SMS_RECEIVED" Action :-/

Comment: @CommonsWare: ok, i understand! I thought this, but I could not find confirmation. What should I do with my question, delete this?

Comment: You can delete it if you want or leave it here. Perhaps your question will happen to fit somebody else's search, and they can then continue along to the duplicate question and its answers.